# Enabling Rails CloudFront on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

I followed [this article on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn) to enable CloudFront on my Rails 5 app hosted on Heroku.  However, it doesn't seem to be working for my images (which are hosted on S3).

I have tried setting the `Origin Domain Name` in AWS to both by S3 bucket (selected from the dropdown), as well as my app's domain name.

However, when I look at the source code, the images are still using the S3 URL instead of the being prefaced with the CloudFront URL which leads me to believe that something is not set-up right.

When I look at the source, I can see the some things are using the preface, such as my favicon `https://mycloudfront.cloudfront.net/assets/favicon-28fde7db6babda6b94460b806d567abe4521f8dd77bc3741debadbf30eeecb19.ico`.

I saw this post
[Rails Cloudfront assets not served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336994/rails-cloudfront-assets-not-served), but I'm using `image_tag` on the images showing the S3 URL in the source code.

in production.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://mycloudfront.cloudfront.net/"
```

Comment: config.action_controller.asset_host only replaces paths of assets declared using relative paths. If you use full s3 resource urls. It won't be replaced

Comment: @ashan Thanks!  Is there a way to replace the URL for full S3 resource URLs?